# API design: list of elements or external ressources?

Tags: json, rest, json-api

I am currently specifying an API for my company, in accordance with [JSON API](https://jsonapi.org) specifications.

When retrieving a `members` ressource with a `GET host.com/members/{members_id}`, I need to expose many phone numbers `phones`.

Example:

```
{
"data": {
    "type":"members",
    "id": "1",
    "attribute": {
        "phones": [{
            "phone": "",
            "type": ""
        }]
    }  
},
"relationships": {
    "subscriptions": {
        "links": {
            "related": "host.com/members/id/subscriptions"
        }
    },
    "relations": {
        "links:" {
            "related": "host.com/members/id/relations"
        }
    }
},
"links": {
    "self": "host.com/members/id"
}
}
```

I do not know whether it is relevant to expose a simple list of dictionaries, or if it would be better to create separate ressources accessible at `/members/me/phones/{phones_id}` with a new `relationships` for the `members` linked to `phones`.

To retrieve a `members` in one request, I could then do a `GET /members/{members_id}?include=phones`.

From my developer point of view, it would be easier to access separate ressources rather than managing and posting lists, especially for phones (e.g. delete only one phone), but I would be very happy to have your (too often relevant) external advices.

Thanks for your support !

Comment: seems like both the ways you're thinking of using would work? seems compliant both ways and you get to choose what you want to do... personally i don't think there's all that much data you can put in a standalone phone resource, and maybe you want to make this decision based on uniqueness (ie, can 2 users share the same phone resource?)

Answer (score 0):

Can you modify your JSON response? because it is not ideal.
this ideal:

```
 GET host.com/members/{members_id}
```

returns:

```
{
    "id": "1",
    "phones": [{
            "phone": "",
            "type": ""
        }
      ]
}
```

GET host.com/members/{members_id}/phones

```
[           
    {
                "phone": "",
                "type": ""
            },
           {
                "phone": "",
                "type": ""
            }
]
```